# Update Query depending on Date

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

```
RN_TESTCYCL_ID
RN_CYCLE_ID
RN_TEST_ID
RN_RUN_ID
RN_RUN_NAME
RN_EXECUTION_DATE (if RN_VTS Null, compare with this Date, format: DDMMYY)
RN_EXECUTION_TIME
RN_HOST
RN_STATUS
RN_DURATION
RN_TESTER_NAME
RN_PATH
RN_USER_01
RN_USER_02
RN_USER_03
RN_USER_04
RN_USER_05
RN_USER_06
RN_USER_07
RN_USER_08
RN_USER_09
RN_USER_10
RN_USER_11
RN_USER_12
RN_TEST_VERSION
RN_ATTACHMENT
RN_RUN_VER_STAMP
RN_VTS (compare with current Date, sometimes Null, Format: YYYYMMDDHH24MISS)
RN_CYCLE
RN_TEST_INSTANCE
RN_OS_NAME
RN_OS_SP
RN_OS_BUILD
RN_VC_LOKEDBY
RN_VC_STATUS
RN_VC_VERSION
RN_OS_CONFIG
RN_ASSIGN_RCYC
RN_BPTA_CHANGE_DETECTED
RN_BPTA_CHANGE_AWARENESS
RN_VC_VERSION_NUMBER
RN_PINNED_BASELINE
RN_TEST_CONFIG_ID
RN_DRAFT
RN_ITERS_PARAMS_VALUES
RN_ITERS_SUM_STATUS
RN_BPT_STRUCTURE
RN_STATE
RN_COMMENTS
RN_SUBTYPE_ID
RN_TEXT_SYNC
RN_ENVIRONMENT
RN_BUILD_REVISION
RN_DETAIL
RN_JENKINS_URL
RN_JENKINS_JOB_NAME
RN_RESULTS_FILES_NETWORK_PATH
```

I need to update every RN_Tester_name to "anonymous" if RN_VTS < DateX and if RN_VTS is Null then compare RN_EXECUTION_DATE < DateX

Can someone figure out a query to update RN_Tester_Name, i'm kinda stuck?

Comment: Can you please post full table description where you want to perform update and explain what do you mean by: compare RN_EXECUTION_DATE < DateX

Comment: The question is not clear. Please post a reduced set of sample data, what you need to obtain and what you tried so far, if any. [mcve] can be useful to improve your question

Comment: @Kacper 
I got a loop in VB.Net which iterate over Date Yearly = DateX
Now I want to update the data on my database where RN_VTS < DateX (if null then compare RN_EXECUTION_DATE < DateX)

Answer (score 0):

Use [coalesce](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions030.htm#SQLRF00617) SQL function to select the first non-null column. Here you see an example [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle)[sql](/questions/tagged/sql) update statement:

```
update X set
rn_tester_name = 'anonymous'
where coalesce(rn_vts, rn_execution_date) < Y
```

I don't know how you can use that in your [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) code thought.